# ArcMap Layer Time Export Using A Time Window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, timeslider

I currently have a layer with around 17,000 entries with time data formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS as a string. ArcMap can correctly display the time and and I have applied an hour time window to show all of the available data points from a one hour window (for example: show all points in the range of 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM). ArcMap will correctly play this animation in the time slider by clicking play.

The issue arises when I go to export this as either a AVI or sequential images. Arc begins the export and ignores the time window and only shows 1:00 PM instead of the one hour window from 1-2. Because there is almost no data falling on the exact hour, the export fails to produce what just played in the time slider before exporting.

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCJDP.jpg

Comment: create a SQL query to only show your time window, export that data then create a new animation. export animation.

Comment: My issue is I am trying to do this for each hour so manually updating the SQL query would be painful. For example `3/1/2015 1-2, 3/1/2015 2-3, 3/1/2015 3-4`. The timeslider can do it automatically but only fails on export. I can't figure out the reasoning.

Comment: Please use the picture button to embed your screenshot within your question.